# DIV position not to exceed bottom of page

Tags: css, html, css-position

I got an issue position a div element within a page. My problem is that I have a navigation bar with a hierarchical 3-level menu. When I open some of the 3rd level menus the element containing the items goes below the page height. I'd like to keep this element in the page area, maybe moving the top position, so the user can keep use it without scrolling (that is also problematic).

You could see an example here: http://www.frankydev.com/mitoweb/

Many thanks.

Comment: Make menu smaller on smallers screens with media queries. (smaller font, padding)

Answer (score 0):

I see it even happens on large screens.
Limit the height of the 3rd menu div with `max-height`, say 300px and then add `overflow-y:scroll;`.  This will add an up-down scroll bar to the 3rd menu element and it looks relatively nice.
Or change all your font size and spacing to allow more room.